why is my client sending a extra request to the server
io.on("connection", (socket)=>{
    console.log(socket.id)
    const cookiesHeader = socket.request.headers.cookie;

    if (cookiesHeader) {
        // Manually parse cookies
        const cookies = cookiesHeader.split(';').reduce((acc, cookie) => {
            const [key, value] = cookie.split('=');
            acc[key.trim()] = decodeURIComponent(value.trim());
            return acc;
        }, {});
        const token = cookies.Token
        console.log(token)
    }


   
})

Hello everyone,
I'm working on a project using Socket.IO, and I'm running into a couple of issues that I'm having trouble resolving. I would really appreciate any help or suggestions!
Multiple Requests:
My client seems to be sending two requests back-to-back to the server. I suspect this might be related to how the connection is being handled, but I'm not sure why this is happening. I would appreciate any insights or solutions for preventing this duplication of requests.
Slow Connection Establishment:
The connection between the client and server is taking a significant amount of time to establish. I’ve checked the network conditions and server performance, but the issue persists. Are there any common causes for slow connection times with Socket.IO or any recommended optimizations?

what does that code in the question have to do with the client sending two requests?
